# Sourcing AppSettings from database & cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, refactoring, web-config

At my office, it has been deemed that we are to put our AppSettings for the Web.Config in the database.  As such, I created the following, but have some doubts about a couple aspects of the code.

**So my question is:**
The line containing "Cache cache = new Cache()" in the UTILITY class is probably wrong because it creates a NEW cache object.

Q: So, what should I be doing for that line?

...any help is appreciated.

**The overall objective was to be able to make a call like this:**

```
Utility.GetConfigurationValue(ConfigurationSection.AppSettings, "myVariable");
```

...and have it retrieve from the cache or the database auto-magically.

**THE UTILITY CODE:**

```
public static class Utility
{
    #region "Configurations"

    public static String GetConfigurationValue(ConfigurationSection section, String key)
    {
        Configurations config = new Configurations();
        Cache cache = new Cache(); // <--- This is probably wrong!!!!

        if (!cache.TryGetItemFromCache<Configurations>(out config))
        {
            config.List(SNCLavalin.US.Common.Enumerations.ConfigurationSection.AppSettings);
            cache.AddToCache<Configurations>(config, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15));
        }

        var result = (from record in config
                      where record.Key == key
                      select record).FirstOrDefault();

        return (result == null) ? null : result.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**THE EXTENSION CODE:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    #region "System.Web.Caching"

    public static void Remove<T>(this Cache cache) where T : class
    {
        cache.Remove(typeof(T).Name);
    }
    public static void AddToCache<T>(this Cache cache, object item, DateTime absoluteExpiration) where T : class
    {
        T outItem = null;
        if (cache.TryGetItemFromCache<T>(out outItem))
            return;

        cache.Insert(typeof(T).Name,
                item,
                null,
                absoluteExpiration,
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                null);
    }
    public static bool TryGetItemFromCache<T>(this Cache cache, out T item) where T : class
    {
        item = cache.Get(typeof(T).Name) as T;
        return item != null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**THE LIST-CLASS CODE:**

```
public class Configurations : List<Configuration>
{
    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public Configurations() : base()
    {
        initialize();
    }
    public Configurations(int capacity) : base(capacity)
    {
        initialize();
    }
    public Configurations(IEnumerable<Configuration> collection) : base(collection)
    {
        initialize();
    }

    #endregion

    #region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

    private Crud _crud;

    #endregion

    #region EVENTS
    #endregion

    #region METHODS

    private void initialize()
    {
        _crud = new Crud("CurrentDbConnection");
    }

    public Configurations List(ConfigurationSection section)
    {
        using (DbCommand dbCommand = _crud.Db.GetStoredProcCommand("spa_LIST_SecConfiguration"))
        {
            _crud.Db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Section", DbType.String, section.ToString());

            _crud.List(dbCommand, PopulateFrom);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public void PopulateFrom(DataTable table)
    {
        this.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Configuration instance = new Configuration();
            instance.PopulateFrom(row);
            this.Add(instance);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**THE ITEM-CLASS CODE:**

public class Configuration
{
    #region CONSTRUCTORS

```
public Configuration()
{
    initialize();
}

#endregion

#region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

private Crud _crud;

public string Section { get; set; }
public string Key { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }

#endregion

#region EVENTS
#endregion

#region METHODS

private void initialize()
{
    _crud = new Crud("CurrentDbConnection");
    Clear();
}

public void Clear()
{
    this.Section = "";
    this.Key = "";
    this.Value = "";
}
public void PopulateFrom(DataRow row)
{
    Clear();

    this.Section = row["Section"].ToString();
    this.Key = row["Key"].ToString();
    this.Value = row["Value"].ToString();
}

#endregion
```

}

Comment: Why is it deemed that we should put our AppSettings in database? It gets cached after application starts.

Comment: @Frennky: Thanks for the comment...my boss deemed WE must get all our AppSettings from the database for 2 own reasons: changing anything in the web.config boots people from the application; people kept screwing-up the web.config on releases. As such, this is my first attempt at the issue. So...any comments on the question above would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified the problem - the current code creates a new `Cache` instance on each call to `GetConfigurationValue` which defeats the purpose of caching. You need to make the Cache instance static rather than creating a new instance each time.

```
public static class Utility
{
    private static Cache cache = new Cache();  // Static class variable

    #region "Configurations"

    public static String GetConfigurationValue(ConfigurationSection section, String key)
    {
        Configurations config = new Configurations();
        // Cache cache = new Cache(); --- removed

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I will be trying that today!

Comment: Originally, I was thinking I needed to point to an object that already existed.  But I thought HttpContext.Current.Cache would be the wrong object to pass-in and use...so I prompted folks here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**ADDENDUM TO ANSWER:**
I did (in fact) need to point the cache variable to something else.  It wouldn't work until I did the following in the Utility class.

```
private static Cache cache = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache;
```